# Evaluating a function at a particular value in parallel

Tags: algorithm, math, parallel-processing

The question may seem vague, but let me explain it.

Suppose we have a function f(x,y,z ....) and we need to find its value at the point (x1,y1,z1 .....).

The most trivial approach is to just replace (x,y,z ...) with (x1,y1,z1 .....).

Now suppose that the function is taking a lot of time in evaluation and I want to parallelize the algorithm to evaluate it. Obviously it will depend on the nature of function, too.

So my question is: what are the constraints that I have to look for while "thinking" to parallelize f(x,y,z...)?

If possible, please share links to study.

Comment: Please supply more information on what type of function you want to parallelise. Examples would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking the question in such a general way does not permit very specific advice to be given.

I'd begin the analysis by looking for ways to evaluate or rewrite the function using groups of variables that interact closely, creating intermediate expressions that can be used to make the final evaluation.  You may find a way to do this involving a hierarchy of subexpressions that leads from the variables themselves to the final function.

In general the shorter and wider such an evaluation tree is, the greater the degree of parallelism.  There are two cautionary notes to keep in mind that detract from "more parallelism is better."

For one thing a highly parallel approach may actually involve more total computation than your original "serial" approach.  In fact some loss of efficiency in this regard is to be expected, since a serial approach can take advantage of all prior subexpression evaluations and maximize their reuse.

For another thing the parallel evaluation will often have worse rounding/accuracy behavior than a serial evaluation chosen to give good or optimal error estimates.

A lot of work has been done on evaluations that involve matrices, where there is usually a lot of symmetry to how the function value depends on its arguments.  So it helps to be familiar with numerical linear algebra and parallel algorithms that have been developed there.

Another area where a lot is known is for multivariate polynomial and rational functions.

When the function is transcendental, one might hope for some transformations or refactoring that makes the dependence more tractable (algebraic).

Not directly relevant to your question are algorithms that amortize the cost of computing function values across a number of arguments.  For example in computing solutions to ordinary differential equations, there may be "multi-step" methods that share the cost of evaluating derivatives at intermediate points by reusing those values several times.

I'd suggest that your concern to speed up the evaluation of the function suggests that you plan to perform more than one evaluation.  So you might think about ways to take advantage of prior evaluations or perform evaluations at related arguments in a way that contributes to your search for parallelism.

**Added:**  Some links and discussion of search strategy

Most authors use the phrase "parallel function evaluation" to
mean evaluating the same function at multiple argument points.

See for example:

[Coarse Grained Parallel Function Evaluation -- Rulon and Youssef]
http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/401028/files/p837.pdf

A search strategy to find the kind of material Gaurav Kalra asks
about should try to avoid those.  For example, we might include
"fine-grained" in our search terms.

It's also effective to focus on specific kinds of functions, e.g.
"polynomial evaluation" rather than "function evaluation".

Here for example we have a treatment of some well-known techniques
for "fast" evaluations applied to design for GPU-based computation:

[How to obtain efficient GPU kernels -- Cruz, Layton, and Barba]
http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1009/1009.3457v1.pdf

(from their Abstract) "Here, we have tackled fast summation
algorithms (fast multipole method and fast Gauss transform),
and applied algorithmic redesign for attaining performance on
GPUs. The progression of performance improvements attained
illustrates the exercise of formulating algorithms for the
massively parallel architecture of the GPU."

Another search term that might be worth excluding is "pipelined".
This term invariably discusses the sort of parallelism that can
be used when multiple function evaluations are to be done.  Early
stages of the computation can be done in parallel with later 
stages, but on different inputs.

So that's a search term that one might want to exclude.  Or not.

Here's a paper that discusses n-fold speedup for n-variate
polynomial evaluation over finite fields GF(p).  This might be
of direct interest for cryptographic applications, but the 
approach via modified Horner's method may be interesting for
its potential for generalization:

[Comparison of Bit and Word Level Algorithms for Evaluating
 Unstructured Functions over Finite Rings -- Sunar and Cyganski]
http://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2005/018.pdf

"We present a modification to Horner’s algorithm for evaluating
arbitrary n-variate functions defined over finite rings and fields.
... If the domain is a finite field GF(p) the complexity of
multivariate Horner polynomial evaluation is improved from O(p^n)
to O((p^n)/(2n)). We prove the optimality of the presented algorithm."

Multivariate rational functions can be considered simply as the
ratio of two such polynomial functions.  For the special case
of univariate rational functions, which can be particularly
effective in approximating elementary transcendental functions
and others, can be evaluated via finite (resp. truncated)
continued fractions, whose convergents (partial numerators
and denominators) can be defined recursively.

The topic of continued fraction evaluations allows us to segue
to a final link that connects that topic with some familiar
parallelism of numerical linear algebra:

[LU Factorization and Parallel Evaluation of Continued Fractions
  -- Ömer Egecioglu]
http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~omer/DOWNLOADABLE/lu-cf98.pdf

"The first n convergents of a general continued fraction
(CF) can be computed optimally in logarithmic parallel
time using O(n/log(n))processors."

Answer (score 1):

You've asked how to speed up the evalution of a single call to a single function.  Unless that evaluation time is measured in hours, it isn't clear why it is worth the bother to speed it up.  If you insist on speeding up the function execution itself,  you'll have to inspect its content to see if some aspects of it are parallelizable.  You haven't provided any information on what it computes or how it does so, so it is hard to give any further advice on this aspect.  hardmath's answer suggests some ideas you can use, depending on the actual internal structure of your function.

However, usually people asking your question actually call the function many times (say, N times) for different values of x,y,z (eg., x1,y1,... x2,y2,...  xN,yN, ... using your vocabulary).
Yes, if you speed up the execution of the function, making the collective set of calls will speed up and that's what people tend to want.   If this is the case, it is "technically easy" to speed up overall execution:  make N calls to the function in parallel.  Then all the pointwise evaluations happen at the same time.  To make this work, you pretty much have make vectors out of the values you want to process (so this kind of trick is called "data parallel" programming).  So what you really want is something like:

```
    PARALLEL DO  I=1,N
          RESULT(I)=F(X[J],Y[J], ...)
    END PARALLEL DO
```

How you implement PARALLEL DO depends on the programming language and libraries you have.
This generally only works if N is a fairly big number, but the more expensive f is to execute, the smaller the effective N.

You can also take advantage of the structure of your function to make this even more efficient.  If f computes some internal value the same way for commonly used cases, you might be able
to break out the special cases, pre-compute those, and then use those results to compute "the rest of f" for each individual call.

If you are combining ("reducing") the results of all the functions (e..g, summing all the results), you can do that *outside* the PARALELL DO loop. If you try to combine results inside the loop, you'll have "loop carried dependencies" and you'll either get the wrong answer or it won't go parallel in the way you expect, depending on your compiler or the parallelism libraries.  You *can* combine the answers efficiently if the combination is some associative/commutative operation such as "sum", by building what amounts to a binary tree and running the evaluation of *that* in parallel.  That's a different problem that also occurs frequently in data parallel computation, but we won't go into further here.

Often the overhead of a parallel for loop is pretty high (forking threads is expensive).  So usually people divide the overhead across several iterations:

```
   PARALLEL DO  I=1,N,M
        DO J=I,I+M
            RESULT(J)=F(X[J],Y[J], ...)
        END DO
   END PARALLEL DO
```

The constant M requires calibration for efficiency; you have to "tune" it.  You also have to take care of the fact that N might not be a multiple of M; that requires just an extra clean loop to handle the edge condition:

```
   PARALLEL DO  I=1,int(N/M)*M,M
        DO J=I,I+M
            RESULT(J)=F(X[J],Y[J], ...)
        END DO
   END PARALLEL DO
   DO J=int(N/M)*M,N,1
            RESULT(J)=F(X[J],Y[J], ...)
   END DO
```